# re-writing a mathematical expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, matlab

I am reading the following paper:

http://www.nova.edu/ocean/Physics/PDF/Solovievetal2007.pdf

and am trying to write a MATLAB program to solve equation 1.26, which is shown as:

$$ K_{int} = \frac{A_{0} u_{*} \left(1 - a_{0}^3 \Lambda_{0}^4 Rf_{0}\right)^{1/4}}{Sc^{1/2}\Lambda_{0} \left( 1 + Ke / Ke_{cr} \right)^{1/2}} f\left(Rf_{0}, Ke, A_{w}\right), $$

where

$$ f = \left[  1 + \frac{39.5 W}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3/2}A_{0}^4} \left(\frac{1}{W^{1/4}} - 1 \right) \\ \left( \frac{3}{BS_{q}}\right)^{1/2} \left( \frac{\rho \nu^{2} Ke} {\rho_{a} \nu_{a}^{2} Ke_{cr}} \right)^{1/2} \frac{\alpha_{w} a_{0}^{3} \Lambda_{0}^4 \left( 1 + Ke/Ke_{cr}\right)^{1/2}} {\left( 1 - a_{0}^{3} \Lambda_{0}^{4} Rf_{0} \right) \kappa c_{T} A_{w}^{1/2} R_{Bcr}}  \right]^{1/4} $$

My question is: how do I re-write this into one equation? Does $f$ substitute for $f\left( Rf_{0}, Ke, A_{w}\right)$, so that the full equation is written as:

$$ K_{int} = \frac{A_{0} u_{*} \left(1 - a_{0}^3 \Lambda_{0}^4 Rf_{0}\right)^{1/4}}{Sc^{1/2}\Lambda_{0} \left( 1 + Ke / Ke_{cr} \right)^{1/2}} \left[  1 + \frac{39.5 W}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3/2}A_{0}^4} \left(\frac{1}{W^{1/4}} - 1 \right) \\ \left( \frac{3}{BS_{q}}\right)^{1/2} \left( \frac{\rho \nu^{2} Ke} {\rho_{a} \nu_{a}^{2} Ke_{cr}} \right)^{1/2} \frac{\alpha_{w} a_{0}^{3} \Lambda_{0}^4 \left( 1 + Ke/Ke_{cr}\right)^{1/2}} {\left( 1 - a_{0}^{3} \Lambda_{0}^{4} Rf_{0} \right) \kappa c_{T} A_{w}^{1/2} R_{Bcr}}  \right]^{1/4} $$

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: First time I see this tag!

Comment: Please tag your question so that the tags tell what the problem _is_ about, rather than what it's _not_ about. You seem to have substituted $f$ correctly; probably this is what the paper means.

Comment: I'm not sure what tag to use. If I have substituted f correctly, why does the paper not just do this in the first place?

Comment: They want to emphasize the relevant variables, the other variables are material constants, physical constants and such which probably stay constant for the researched situations.

Comment: @EmmaTebbs They also use $f$ again in a second expression on the next page, so its more efficient to define it separately. (It also prevents the formula from $K_{\mathrm{int}}$ from breaking over three lines, which would make it harder to read.)

Comment: @EmmaTebbs I agree this is a slightly difficult question to tag - myself and another user have now retagged it. Physics and matlab are both relevant to the context, and I also added algebra-precalc because it's essentially about manipulating expressions (although the expressions are a little more involved than those that would normally occur under this tag!).

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly suggest just using it as two different expressions. I am assuming that you are going to be using the fzero() function, which takes a function handle as an argument.

To do this, go create a MATLAB function file, and put a function in it called Kint, which contains the above two expressions, and returns Kint. Make the input whichever variable you want to solve for.

Then go to the command-line and type: fzero(@Kint,) where  is the initial guess for a solution, and the starting point for the search.

Comment: Why would someone need to use fzero for this? Could you provide an example of how it would be used in this case?

Comment: Can you tell me which variable you are trying to solve for?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate Kint